# how do make vue-canvas-gauges colorMajorTicks and colorMinorTicks progress height auto changes to value?

Tags: vue.js

[vue-canvas-gauges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leHAJ.png)

how do vue-canvas-gauges colorMajorTicks and colorMinorTicks change to value? but Does not color completely level.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.